# Receiving Error: 'apxs' command appears not to be installed

Tags: python, django

This is the error I am receiving:
`RuntimeError: The 'apxs' command appears not to be installed or is not executable. Please check the list of prerequisites in the documentation for this package and install any missing Apache httpd server packages.`

How can I get around this? I have received this while trying to install different packages. I am working on a Django project. I have already made sure the `apache2-dev` package is installed. I am developing on linux.

Answer (score 1):

You can add some dependencies to the apache2.

`sudo apt-get -y install apache2 apache2-utils apache2-dev`

This helped me go around the missing apxs.